# Unable to redirect to recently created detailview

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am getting the below error when attempting to redirect to my newly created conversation detail page.

> NoReverseMatch at /conversations/start/
> Reverse for 'conversation_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['conversations/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

The slug works perfectly when I type the URL manually so I think it has to do with the return reverse logic on the `StartConversationView`.

Please let me know of anything else I could try (I've tried what's commented below).

**models.py**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    conversation = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=False, unique=False)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=False, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.conversation
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.conversation+'-'+str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")))
            super(Conversation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('conversation_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
        return reverse('conversation_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**views.py**

```
class StartConversationView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = StartConversationForm()
        return render(request, 'conversations/start.html', {'form': form})
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = StartConversationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_conversation = form.save(commit=False)            
            new_conversation.starter = request.user            
            new_conversation.save()
            messages.success(request, ('You have successfully started a new conversation.'))       
            return redirect(reverse('conversation_detail'), slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
            #return redirect(reverse('conversation_detail'), kwargs = {'slug': self.slug })
            #return redirect('conversation_detail'), self.slug=slug)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('conversation_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug}))
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(self.get_absolute_url()))
            #return redirect('login')
        return render(request, 'conversations/start.html' , {'form': form})


class ConversationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Conversation
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = 'conversations/conversation_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('start_circle/',StartCircleView.as_view(), name='start_circle'),
    path('start/',StartConversationView.as_view(), name='start_conversation'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',ConversationDetailView.as_view(), name='conversation_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
class StartConversationView(View):

    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = StartConversationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_conversation = form.save(commit=False)            
            new_conversation.starter = request.user            
            new_conversation.save()
            messages.success(request, ('You have successfully started a new conversation.'))       
           
            return redirect(reverse('conversation_detail', kwargs={'slug':new_conversation.slug}))

             
        return render(request, 'detail.html' , {'form': form})
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much sir. the only thing I had to modify was return render(request, 'conversation_detail' , {'form': form})